# Сетка блоков flex

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую сетку из flex (см.на картинке), может есть пример

При максимальной ширине 1150px, должны становиться в ряд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *При максимальной ширине 1150px, должны становиться в ряд* - это как?

Comment: Картинки идут друг за другом по горизонтали

Comment: @entithat flex-wrap:wrap

Comment: Одноуровневым flexом никак. grid справится

Comment: @xaja, ну "никак" - это не совсем правда - извратиться по-всякому можно, но да, гридом лучше.

Comment: @xaja, всё, окостылил)))

Comment: @xaja, и грид сделал.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ одним (одноуровневым) флексом без вложенностей?

Comment: ах, сорри, увидел ваш ответ ниже. да. сильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .main {
    height: 330px;
    width: 400px;
  }
  
  .nested {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
  .nested > .item {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
  .break {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item main"></div>
  <div class="nested">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="break"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 4):

Жуткие костыли на флексе с плоским размещением:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  background: silver;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 1.333% 1.333% 0 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

div:first-child, div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

div:first-child {
  width: 65.778%;
  margin-bottom: -25%;
}

div:first-child::before {
  padding-top: 52%;
}

div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 32.889%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 67.111%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1):

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;

фиксировано задавай ширины и высоты блоков!

Answer (score 1):

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1.28fr .72fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

div {
  background: silver;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

div:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 5;
}

div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```